# How to iterate through multiple database servers in Flask Mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am looking to loop through 2 database servers to get a match for the query submitted through form(example.html) ie iterating the configuration value (`app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']`). If no data is retrieved from first database server it needs to query with the second one. When I try to make a list to iterate through the mysql hosts,
it shows me `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Below is the work code when I set one database server in `app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']`. `db.yaml` file contains the database server and configuration information.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)


db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))

app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']


mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/')

def dashboard():

    return render_template('dashboard.html')


@app.route('/sdetails')

def sdetails():

    return render_template('s.html')


@app.route('/s', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

def s():


    dbhosts = yaml.load(open('yamlsample.yaml'))
    dbhosts = list(dbhosts)


    if request.method == 'POST':

        result = request.form
        sname = request.form["Name"]


    for i in dbhosts:

        app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = i
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        slist=cur.execute(slist=cur.execute("select * from table1 WHERE table1.name LIKE '{}'".format(sname))


        sdetails=cur.fetchall()

        if sdetails != None:

            return render_template('results.html', sdetails=sdetails)

        else:

            continue  # I thought continue will take me to the next dbhost. But not happening.

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug = True)
```

I am making use of db.yaml only for database username,password and database server.

### db.yaml

mysql_user: 'xxxx'
mysql_password: 'xxxxx'
mysql_db: 'xxxxx'

I am making use of yamlsample.yaml for iterating  over DB hosts only.

### yamlsample.yaml

- 192.168.1.10
- 192.168.1.11

Comment: please post your db.yaml file content

Comment: Thanks Mousa. Yaml file updated. (I have used hyphen in yamlsample,yaml. However here in the post as bullets). So please consider this as hyphen (-) .